# Bug in Ubuntu Terminal [22.04]

Tags: command-line, 22.04

I have a problem that occurs in my Ubuntu terminal, there is an offset that always ends up appearing at the bottom and I can't scroll to the last line.

For information, I use a custom Ubuntu theme, I wonder if there is some correlation.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Screen size (number of rows/columns) is a setting in your current profile under Preferences. Did you perhaps set it to a unusual number of rows?

Comment: @Jos I think I might have found the issue, the "Scroll on output" option in Preferences was unchecked, do you think this was the cause?

Comment: No, `Scroll on output` is unchecked in my Preferences as well, and my terminal window perfectly covers my screen, at 57 lines and 212 columns.

Comment: Ok, I have 80 columns and 24 rows in the Initial terminal size sections of Preferences, should I modify it?

Comment: You have far more than 24 rows, and more than 80 characters as well. You have probably maximized your window (I can't tell from your screenshot), which overrules the screen size. Do you have a multi-monitor setup with another, larger monitor? If the window was maximized, you might try to restore the window size by pressing Alt + space and choose "restore" from the menu.

Comment: I work on my laptop at the moment, no extra monitor. I indeed maximised the window, I'll see if pressing Alt + space... solves the issue when it happens

Answer (score 1):

Experimenting with maximizing the window on my own system, it appears that if the font you are using has a size that doesn't divide evenly into your screen size, you end up with a fragment of a line at the bottom of the window.

The scroll on output option hides this a little bit, as it will *usually* leave the last visible line on in the terminal on the last whole line in the window.  But if you scroll back, the fragment is used again.  Probably other things would make this happen too.

An alternative is to stretch the window manually rather than maximizing it, as mouse resizing the window will resize in increments of line heights and character widths.  You still end up with a fragment of a line at the bottom of your screen -- but it will be outside the window as a gap between the window edge and the screen edge.